# File Reader not working properly?

Tags: java, file, infinite-loop, filereader, eof

I have the following code and for some reason the end of file is never reached so the while loop never does end.

```
public class Temp {
FileReader fr;

Temp() {
    try {
        fr = new FileReader("File path");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Temp ob = new Temp();

    try {
        char c;
        while ((c = (char) ob.fr.read()) != -1) {
            System.out.println(c);
        }
        ob.fr.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Can any one help me solve this !? thanks in advance :)

Comment: This is so bad, where did you get this from? What are you trying to do, and somebody will point you to a better reference, because this is java that should not be used.

Comment: @matt I just re visited the file reader topic. And I forgot the basics. ;)

Comment: So, the FileReader is heavily discouraged against using because of a lack of character encoding. A better option would be to use the [Files.newBufferedReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedReader-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.charset.Charset-). The next thing you should use is [ARM](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). I don't mean to be too negative, but as you have just started this program, it would be much better to look at using the currently correct techniques. Cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're comparing `c` - a `char`, which is an *unsigned* type - with -1. Don't do that. It's promoting `c` to `int`, so you'll end up with 65535 instead. Instead, make `c` an `int` and do the cast to `char` inside the body of the loop.

```
int c;
while ((c = ob.fr.read()) != -1) {
    System.out.println((char) c);
}
```

I'd also advise against creating a new object just for the sake of storing something in a variable... you could have used a local variable for the `FileReader` here.

I'd also advise:

- Not just continuing if an exception is thrown, as if nothing had gone wrong
- Using try-with-resources instead of manually closing the reader
- Avoiding `FileReader` to start with as it always uses the default encoding. (Use a `FileInputStream` with an `InputStreamReader`, or from Java 7 just use [`Files.newBufferedReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedReader-java.nio.file.Path-).)